# Writing a .bat file that will delete orphaned registry keys in the profile list and it is not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, windows-registry

Need to write a .bat file that will loop through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, check if the SID actually has a user folder on the machine and if not, delete the folder from ProfileList. I'm blanking on how to implement it actually deleting it.

This is what I have so far:

```
for /f "tokens=3* usebackq" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /S ^| find "ProfileImagePath"`) do (
    echo Found user profile [%%a]

if exist %%a (
echo OK
) ELSE (
echo ORPHANED REGISTRY KEY - DELETED

) 

)
pause
```

Comment: Although possible in batch, powershell is a better way to approach this task.

Comment: How would I do that in Powershell then? Where do I go from this? We want to delete any reg key where the user folder dosen't exist by checking ProfileImagePath
$Key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'

Get-ChildItem $Key -Rec -EA SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {


}